# iOS Photopicker gives 52 issues (24 errors, 28 warnings)

Tags: ios, camera, compiler-errors, warnings, uiimagepickercontroller

I downloaded the Apple Photopicker example from http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/PhotoPicker/Introduction/Intro.html.

When I build it, it gives me 52 issues (24 errors, 28 warnings) without me changing anything. I am building to my device and also tried the simulator without any success. Can someone tell me if I need to change any settings on my Xcode which is current? I am using iOS 5.1 on the phone and set my deployment target to the same. Thanks!

Here are the errors:

Unknown receiver '_imageView'; did you mean 'UIImageView'?

Unknown receiver '_myToolbar'; did you mean 'UIToolbar'?

Unknown receiver '_overlayViewController'; did you mean 'OverlayViewController'?

Use of undeclared identifier '_capturedImages'

Property 'myToolbar' requires method 'myToolbar' to be defined - use @synthesize, @dynamic or provide a method implementation in this class implementation

Property 'myToolbar' requires method 'setMyToolbar:' to be defined - use @synthesize, @dynamic or provide a method implementation in this class implementation

Property 'overlayViewController' requires method 'overlayViewController' to be defined - use @synthesize, @dynamic or provide a method implementation in this class implementation

Property 'overlayViewController' requires method 'setOverlayViewController:' to be defined - use @synthesize, @dynamic or provide a method implementation in this class implementation

Property 'capturedImages' requires method 'capturedImages' to be defined - use @synthesize, @dynamic or provide a method implementation in this class implementation

Property 'capturedImages' requires method 'setCapturedImages:' to be defined - use @synthesize, @dynamic or provide a method implementation in this class implementation

Property 'imageView' requires method 'imageView' to be defined - use @synthesize, @dynamic or provide a method implementation in this class implementation

Property 'imageView' requires method 'setImageView:' to be defined - use @synthesize, @dynamic or provide a method implementation in this class implementation
Use of undeclared identifier '_tickSound'

Use of undeclared identifier '_takePictureButton'

Use of undeclared identifier '_startStopButton'

Use of undeclared identifier '_cancelButton'

Use of undeclared identifier '_timedButton'

Unknown receiver '_imagePickerController'; did you mean 'UIImagePickerController'?

Use of undeclared identifier '_tickSound'

Use of undeclared identifier '_cameraTimer'

Use of undeclared identifier '_tickTimer'

Use of undeclared identifier '_cameraTimer'

Use of undeclared identifier '_tickTimer'

Use of undeclared identifier '_cameraTimer'

Use of undeclared identifier '_tickTimer'

Use of undeclared identifier '_cameraTimer'

Use of undeclared identifier '_cameraTimer'

Use of undeclared identifier '_cameraTimer'

Use of undeclared identifier '_tickTimer'

Property 'tickSound' requires method 'tickSound' to be defined - use @synthesize, @dynamic or provide a method implementation in this class implementation

Property 'tickSound' requires method 'setTickSound:' to be defined - use @synthesize, @dynamic or provide a method implementation in this class implementation

Property 'cameraTimer' requires method 'cameraTimer' to be defined - use @synthesize, @dynamic or provide a method implementation in this class implementation

Property 'cameraTimer' requires method 'setCameraTimer:' to be defined - use @synthesize, @dynamic or provide a method implementation in this class implementation

Property 'tickTimer' requires method 'tickTimer' to be defined - use @synthesize, @dynamic or provide a method implementation in this class implementation

Property 'tickTimer' requires method 'setTickTimer:' to be defined - use @synthesize, @dynamic or provide a method implementation in this class implementation

Property 'timedButton' requires method 'timedButton' to be defined - use @synthesize, @dynamic or provide a method implementation in this class implementation

Property 'timedButton' requires method 'setTimedButton:' to be defined - use @synthesize, @dynamic or provide a method implementation in this class implementation

Property 'imagePickerController' requires method 'imagePickerController' to be defined - use @synthesize, @dynamic or provide a method implementation in this class implementation

Property 'imagePickerController' requires method 'setImagePickerController:' to be defined - use @synthesize, @dynamic or provide a method implementation in this class implementation

Property 'cancelButton' requires method 'cancelButton' to be defined - use @synthesize, @dynamic or provide a method implementation in this class implementation

Property 'cancelButton' requires method 'setCancelButton:' to be defined - use @synthesize, @dynamic or provide a method implementation in this class implementation

Property 'takePictureButton' requires method 'takePictureButton' to be defined - use @synthesize, @dynamic or provide a method implementation in this class implementation

Property 'takePictureButton' requires method 'setTakePictureButton:' to be defined - use @synthesize, @dynamic or provide a method implementation in this class implementation

Property 'startStopButton' requires method 'startStopButton' to be defined - use @synthesize, @dynamic or provide a method implementation in this class implementation

Property 'startStopButton' requires method 'setStartStopButton:' to be defined - use @synthesize, @dynamic or provide a method implementation in this class implementation

Use of undeclared identifier 'window'

Use of undeclared identifier '_navController'

Use of undeclared identifier '_window'

Property 'navController' requires method 'navController' to be defined - use @synthesize, @dynamic or provide a method implementation in this class implementation

Property 'navController' requires method 'setNavController:' to be defined - use @synthesize, @dynamic or provide a method implementation in this class implementation

Property 'window' requires method 'window' to be defined - use @synthesize, @dynamic or provide a method implementation in this class implementation

Property 'window' requires method 'setWindow:' to be defined - use @synthesize, @dynamic or provide a method implementation in this class implementation

Comment: You need to list the errors in your question.  We cannot guess what your errors might br.

Comment: Those samples might be made for an earlier XCode version. So due some changes in the new XCode this problem can popup.

Comment: What kind of errors? Code signing identity? Linker errors?

Comment: I added the errors to the original question. Note this is directly from the Apple provided example and I wonder why it doesn't work when I built it?

Comment: quite strange... I tried it on both the simulator and phone (iOS 5.1 and 6.0, respectively), and it works fine (also latest Xcode 4.5)... So the project is up to date and should work fine... Maybe double-check you downloaded all the sources files correctly?